# String split c# but ignore some cases

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to split some txt file according to one string.  In another words, text file includes many "COMPONENT" word and I want to split the text depend on the "COMPONENT" word.

Here is my code :

```
string[] splitComponents(string a)
{
    return a.Split(new String[] { "COMPONENT" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

It is working well but it detects some cases for example " COMPONENT_ " and split the text also which is not proper in my case.  How can I ignore this situation? I only want to split "COMPONENT" word not "COMPONENT_".  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the word COMPONENT always followed by a space when you need the split to occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a regex split on the pattern `COMPONENT(?!_)`:

```cs
string[] splitComponents(string a)
{
    return Regex.Split(a, @"COMPONENT(?!_)");
}
```

Comment: Also for more learn about regex, please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) out!